# Spring boot Check Dto Format with two patterns

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm working with Spring-boot to expose REST Api and I need to check two differents patterns of date for my input DTO.
For now, my code checks the format

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

but I need to give to client possibility to send date also with the format **`"yyyy-MM`.**
One of solutions is tu use annotation @Pattern rather than @JsonFormat annotation but the neede regex to validate the two dates is too long, I want to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: What is the type of the field? java.util.Date?

Comment: Yes. The proposed solution in the first answer works with some modification. I'm using StdDeserializer and it works but I dont know what's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like below,

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter
            = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter1
            = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");

    public CustomDateSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CustomDateSerializer(Class t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize (Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Date date;
        try {
            //if not valid, it will throw ParseException
            date = formatter.parse(value.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            try {
                date = formatter1.parse(value.toString());
            }catch(ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();                    
            }
        }
        gen.writeString(formatter.format(date));
    }
}
```

and

`@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    public Date eventDate;`

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways of achieving this. Two of which are

## 1 JsonDeserialize

Register custom deserializer

```
public class DateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public LocalDatedeserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // .................
    // try multiple formats in a loop here if, success return date if not throw exception
    return something;
   }
}
  @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer .class)
  private LocalDate date;
```

## 2 Use string setter and parse date manually

```
private String someDate;
public LocalDate setSomeDate(String someDate){
  // loop through patterns here and try to parse date, then assign parsed date to 
  // another value you are going to use internally 
  // I usually keep string value as well 
}
```

Comment: I got ```Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type```, It works with StdDeserializer<Date>. Do you know what can be the cause of this error and why to use JsonDeserializer rather than StdDeserializer ?